# How to correctly push/pop an element to an array within Record in ImmutableJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a Record object from ImmutableJS and I'm trying to push an element onto an array of attribute `stack` within Record using `withMutations` as such:

```
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
const InitialState = Record({
  isOpen: true,
  item: null,
  type: '',
  stack: []
});

/* eslint-enable new-cap */
const initialState = new InitialState;

export default function modal(state = initialState, action) {
  ...
  return state.withMutations((ctx) => {
    const newStack = ctx.get('stack');
    newStack.push({
        item: action.item,
        type: action.type
    });

    ctx.set('isOpen', true)
      .set('item', action.item)
      .set('type', action.type)
      .set('stack', newStack);
   });
});
```

However, this seems to unset `stack` attribute in Record.
When I do this, it properly sets the array to `stack`.

```
return state.withMutations((ctx) => {
  ctx...
     .set('stack', [{
       item: action.item,
       type: action.type
     }]);
});
```

Thus,

**Two questions**

A. How can I set `stack` attribute with an array?

B. How should one push/pop objects to an array in ImmutableJS?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is such:

**Push**

```
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
const InitialState = Record({
  isOpen: true,
  item: null,
  type: '',
  stack: List()
});

return state.withMutations((ctx) => {
   ctx...
      .update('stack', stack => stack.push({
        item: action.item,
        type: action.type
      }));
});
```

**Pop**

```
return state.withMutations((ctx) => {
   ctx...
      .update('stack', stack => stack.pop());
});
```